# wxPython Textentrydialog value

Tags: python, wxpython, messagedialog

when I try to use the value I get it gets an empty string

```
    dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, 'Enter User Name:', 'Log in')
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.OK:
       self.user=dlg.GetValue()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [wxPython doc](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MessageDialog.html#MessageDialog.ShowModal). You are mixing up return IDs with `wx.MessageBox`.